# 1 word hangman code, no have repeating letter(amateur). Error is, it doesn't take the first letter compare & I don't know why. Would like to know why?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define maxchar 10
int main(){
  int i=0,n=0,j=0,b=0;
  int m;
  char a[maxchar];
  char s;
  char d[maxchar];
  printf("Welcome to hangman :)\n");
  printf("Enter word with no repeating letters (start with underscore. eg:_time):");
  scanf("%s",a);

  /*n= sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
  for(ii=0;ii<n;ii++)
    d[ii]='_';
  */
  while(a[i]!='\0'){
    i++;
    d[i]='_';
    n++;
  }

  printf("%s",d);
  printf("\nThe total no. of letters is %d\n",n-1);

  while(j!=4){
    printf("\nEnter a letter (don't repeat):\n");
    scanf("%s",&s);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      if(a[i]==s){
        printf("correct and at position %d\n",i);
        d[i]=s;
        printf("%.*s\n",n,d);
        b++;
        break;
      }

    if(b==(n-1)){
      printf("\nHurray!! U guessed the word");
      return 0;
    }
    m=j;
    if(i==n)
      j++;

    if(m<j)
    {
      if(j==1)
        printf(" !\n o\n\n");
      else if(j==2)
        printf(" !\n o\n |\n\n");
      else if(j==3)
        printf(" !\n o\n-|-\n\n");
      else if(j==4){
        printf(" !\n o\n-|-\n ^\n");
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is the 1st character is being omitted from the string.. & I need help to know why that's happening. Hence I used "_word", it works fine then.

I'm still an amateur programmer so the 'space, repeated characters & limited number of checks per character' features are not there. So I urge you to please use same case, no spaces or repeating letter, max 10 chars. Eg: Car, superman, robin, batmobile, spacex etc. will do.

Comment: Welcome. Please learn how to indent your code properly. Currently you are making it **much** harder for someone to help. Also please use full words rather than abbreviations when you are writing the question. Thank you.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&s);` when `s` is of type `char` is wrong.

Comment: My first day(signed in) here. Trying to figure out how things work. Will try to optimize n edit as much as I can. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to learn how to properly ask a question, please read this useful help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To expand on what @user438383 said, please know that whitespace in your code doesn't make it slower or less efficient, and the time spent typing it is well paid for in the time it will save you debugging or adding features.  E.g. `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` i the same as `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` but not unpleasant to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The `"%s"` conversion specifier expects to have a corresponding argument that is of type `char *` that contains the address of a buffer that is large enough to hold the string that is read from the input.  A buffer of size N can hold a string of length N - 1, so the buffer at `&s` can hold a string of length 0.  When `scanf` reads a string, it will write the characters (plus a null terminator) into the buffer.  When you write `char s; scanf("%s", &s)`, there is only enough room for one character.  If `scanf` reads more than 0 characters, it will overflow the buffer when it writes the null terminator and cause undefined behavior.  In general, the correct (well, there really is no correct way to use `scanf`, but that's a different discussion) way to use `"%s"` is with a width specifier that is at most one less than the size of the corresponding buffer.  (eg, `char s[10]; if( scanf("%9s", s) == 1 ) ...`)

But in your case, maybe you just need to use `if( scanf("%c", &s) == 1 ) ...`.

Note: always check the value returned by scanf.  If it does not return the number of conversion specifiers that you expect it to match, then it did not write any data to the corresponding arguments.